# c# If else statement with case insensative

Tags: c#, case-sensitive

I have this if else statement which is assigned to compare results from a text box to a list of context. I am wondering how do i make it such that it is case insensitive ?

```
value = textbox1.Text;

if (article.contains(value))
{   
    label = qwerty;

}
else
{

     break;
{
```

Comment: No, you cannot make the compiler case-insensitive.  The function `Contains` cannot be written as `contains`.

Comment: How is article defined .. is it class, then what are its members?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
if(article.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
{
//   ....
}
else
{
// .....
}
```